# Can't Combine Ctrl Alt Shift

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm a new user in elementary OS and I'm trying to use a shortcut which is a combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, but when I press them it only produces <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your computer otherwise capable of supporting that button combination? I've had keyboards which will allow only to register two of those buttons at any given time.

Comment: Is this an OS level shortcut or an application level shortcut? I've been trying to assign shift+alt+F to format document in VS Code and have discovered alt is being intercepted by Elementary OS even with the appropriate setting configured in VS Code (`window.enableMenuBarMnemonics`.) If that's your issue I've created an issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard/issues/270

Answer (score 0):

I am not in front of a computer right now, so I can't try. But see if you don't press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> if the <kbd>S</kbd> is capital or not